# Use View Transitions API with Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

View Transitions API is now available in stable Chrome.

Link to documentation : https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/view-transitions/

What is the best way to use this with Blazor when navigation occurs ? The documentation provides informations only for React, Vue, Svelte and Lit.